# Conservation of Energy with Chemical and Kinetic Energy of Moving Body

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy-conservation, conservation-laws

A rocket is moving relative to the earth such that it has $E$ joules of kinetic energy. The rocket contains fuel with $E$ joules of chemical energy. The mass of the fuel is negligible in comparison to the rocket. The total energy is $2E$ joules.

The rocket burns the fuel with 100% efficiency such that the rocket is no longer moving relative to the earth. It now has 0 joules of kinetic energy. The total energy is now 0 joules.

The total energy was $2E$ joules and now is 0 joules. What mistake was made to make it seem that this scenario has violated the conservation of energy?

Answer (score 0):

The burned fuel is expelled as reaction mass from the rocket engines.  It carries energy (and momentum) away from the rocket.